# Calculating line integral $\int_{\gamma}K(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$G=\{(x,y,z)^t \in \mathbb{R}^3: y>0,z>0\}$

$K\Big((x,y,z)^t\Big)= \Big(\ln(zy),\frac{x}{y},\beta \frac{x}{z}\Big)$

I want to calculate the line integral $$\int_{\gamma}K(x) dx$$ for $\beta=1$ and $\beta=2$ for $\gamma$ going from $(0,1,1)^t$ *directly* to $(x_0,y_0,z_0)^t$ in $G$.

For $\beta=1$ it's pretty easy because I can use the indefinite integral $F:=x \ln(zy)$ so $\int_{\gamma}K(x) dx = F\Big((x_0,y_0,z_0)^t\Big)-F\Big((0,1,1)^t\Big)=x_0\ln(z_0y_0)$.

Now, for $\beta=2$ there is no such $F$. But apparently one can caluclate the integral using:

$\mathrm {integral(\beta=1)}+\mathrm{what's\ missing}$

Can someone explain to me how this is done? So how do I calculate the line integral for $\beta=2$?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use coherent notation. You cannot  at the same time have  $K(x,y,z)$ and $K(x)$. Furthermore your $dx$ can mean different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write all vectors as row vectors. Let
$$
K_1(x)=\Bigl(\ln(z\,y),\frac{x}{y},\frac{x}{z}\Bigr),\quad K_2(x)=\Bigl(0,0,(\beta-1)\frac{x}{z}\Bigr).
$$
Then
$$
\int_\gamma K(x)\,dx=\int_\gamma K_1(x)\,dx+\int_\gamma K_2(x)\,dx.
$$
The first one you know how to do. The second one can be computed explicitly using the definition of line integral

Comment: Okay thank you. My line is $(t x_0,1+t(y_0-1),1+t(z_0-1))$, so the derivative of it is $(x_0,y_0-1,z_0-1)$. Now using the definition I receive: $\frac{t x_0}{1+t(z_0-1)}(z_0-1)$. But I am not sure from where to where I need to integrate $\int \frac{t x_0}{1+t(z_0-1)}(z_0-1)$?

Comment: $(\beta-1) \frac{t x_0}{1+t(z_0-1)}(z_0-1)$ and $\int (\beta-1)\frac{t x_0}{1+t(z_0-1)}(z_0-1)$ I mean

Comment: Nevermind I got it.

Comment: @Julián Aguirre I have a question to this topic. From where to where do we integrate the second integral? From $0$ to where?

Comment: It depends on the parametrization